# ellipsis: [the people too]

Tags: ellipsis, ambiguity

Does "the people too" in the following mean the council hates the people too? Or the people hates the place too?

> Go to almost any city and you find sink estates where you get the feeling that the council hates the place and the people too.

In case you are unfamiliar with the Britishism "sink estates":

**sink estate/school** *British English* an area where people live or a school that is in a very bad condition and seems unlikely to improve

Comment: I'm not sure what your title is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

> the council hates the place and the people too.

This means the council hates the place, and the council also hates the people.

If it was meant that the people and the council both hate the place, it would be written

> the council hates the place and the people do too.

or phrased less awkwardly

> the council and the people hate the place.

---

Comment: How about "My group will leave tomorrow morning, and yours likewise"? Is this correct?

Comment: @Apollyon that's not wrong, but it sounds rather formal and old-fashioned; I might say "and yours will too" or "as will yours." But note that applying the "...likewise" format to the sink estate sentence will preserve the possible ambiguity.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are other adverbs like "likewise," which can be used with a subject and an implied predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the sentence is deliberately vague.

> **The author is trying to imply both cases the people hate the place and the council hates the people**.

However can you image if the implied, "the council hates the people" where to be written as a factual or even directly suggestive statement?

> Writers and especially journalist often hide behind ambiguous statements. Politicians even more so.

---

> A sink estate is a British term used for a council housing estate with ***high levels of social problems, particularly crime.*** The phrase came into usage in the 1980s, and was used by the Prime Minister, Tony Blair in 1998...

Ref [en.wikipedia.org]

Comment: Saying that the council 'hates the people' is a somewhat dubious politically loaded statement that sounds like something from a right-wing tabloid newspaper, as does the concept of 'sink estates'.

Comment: "... the ‘sink estate’. This derogatory designator, signifying social housing estates that supposedly create poverty, family breakdown, worklessness, welfare dependency, antisocial behaviour and personal irresponsibility, has become the symbolic frame justifying current policies towards social housing that have resulted in considerable social suffering and intensified dislocation. - _The invention of the ‘sink estate’: Consequential categorisation and the UK housing crisis_ (Sociological Review July 2018)